# Find linear approximation to $f(x)=\sin x$ at $x= 0$ and use it to determine sin $2.5^0 $.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

[image]

$x = 0$

$\sin(0) = 0$

---

$2.5^0 = 1$.

---

Equation of the tangent, starts from the derivative.
$f'(x) = \cos(x)$

Slope = $f'(0) = \cos(0) = 1$

---

$y = x  + b$

$0 = x + 0$

$y=x$ (equation of the line)

---

$\sin(2.5^0) = \sin(0) + \cos(0)(1-0)$

$\sin(2.5^0) = 0 + \cos(0)(1-0)$

$\sin(2.5^0) = 1$

---

If I evaluate $\sin(2.5^0)$ with my calculator, I get $0.84$, supposed to my approximation of $1$. I feel this is a bad approximation though. Have I made any errors above?

---

Comment: A few things.  First of all, the linear approximation given by the derivative is $f(\Delta x)\sim f(0)+f'(0)\Delta x$.  Secondly, the derivative of $\sin(x)$ is only $\cos x$ if you measure $x$ in radians.  Third, $2.5 \neq 1$.

Comment: Are you sure that's not asking for the sine of $2.5$ **degrees**, that is, $2.5^\circ$?

Comment: I don't understand "2.5 =1".  Also, with your calculator, it looks like you're mixing up radians and degrees.

Comment: Its 2.5 to the zero. So yeah, $2.5^0 = 1$

Comment: That notation means "$2.5$ degrees".

Comment: Check the updated question, I've added a picture of the question.

Comment: It clearly means degrees.

Comment: Degrees is 'o', this is 0.

Comment: We all get that, by why in the world would someone want you to approximate $\sin 1$ but write $1$ as $2.5^0$? It's a valid way to write $1$, sure, but... incredibly unlikely to be what's meant here. Next up will be $\sin \left( \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k} \right)$ $\ddot \smile$

Comment: I dont know man .... this was an exam question, they do weird stuff like this

Comment: Well, $1$ radian is much too far from $0$ for the linear approximation to have much value.  $1$ degree is certainly close enough, but then the answer would be about $\frac 1{180}\pi\sim 0.017452406$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have , as a first order approximation

$$\sin(x)\approx x$$

but $ x$ must be in Radian.

thus

$\sin(2.5^0)\approx 2.5$ in radian

and finally

$$\sin(2.5^0)\approx \frac{2.5}{180}\pi$$
$$\approx \frac{2.5*3.14}{180}\approx 0.043$$

Comment: Good answer but can you make your last two equations clearer?

Comment: @abnry Please check if it is better.

Comment: No, I meant explain better what is going on. I'm also not sure that $\sin(2.5^0)\approx 2.5$ is correct.

Comment: If you are saying $x$ must be in radians, sin 2.5 radians is 0.59

Answer (score 0):

When using degrees, the derivative comes out differently:

$$\frac d{dx}\sin(x)=\frac\pi{180}\cos(x)$$

Thus, the linear approximation in degrees near $x=0$ is given by

$$\sin(x)=\frac\pi{180}x+\mathcal O(x^2)$$

which then gives

$$\sin(2.5^\circ)\approx\frac\pi{180}(2.5)=\frac\pi{72}=0.043633231$$

in comparison to the actual value:

$$\sin(2.5^\circ)=0.043619387$$

---

The second idea is to take the regular approximation in radians, but convert your number to radians (multiply be $\pi/180$ to turn it into a radian, since $180^\circ=\pi\text{ radians}$):

$$2.5^\circ=2.5\frac\pi{180}=\frac\pi{72}=0.043633231\text{ radian}$$

Then use the radian to get the linear approximation.

Comment: Why do you tackle on the pi/180

Comment: @KSplitX Notice the conversion from degrees to radians is multiplying by $\pi/180$.  Then take the derivative using chain rule and it comes out with the $\pi/180$ out in the front.

Comment: @KSplitX I've added a second part of my answer to explain how one would convert this into a radian, which is more suited for expansions.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the slope of the line is 1.  That means that, for x near 0, sin(x) is roughly equal to x **measured in radians**

I don't know how your calculator came up with 0.84. That's the sine of 57 deg.

Comment: And $1 \text{ rad} = 1 \cdot \frac{180^\circ}{\pi} \approx 57^\circ$; that's approximately the sine of $1$ radian.